# Showing content of argv[1] when submitting job with SGE

Tags: c, linux, unix, sungridengine

Running a program locally I often write a short info about the program state into `argv[1]` (i.e.: 15/100) to estimate how long my program will keep running.
I can then observe the content of `argv[1]` via `top -c`

Is there an equivalent tool to see the content of `argv[1]` when submitting a job via `qsub`?
I did not find an option for `qstat`, that does what I want.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `qstat`. Never done but perhaps you can try with a shell script that runs `ssh <nodes> ps  -fp <pid>` on the nodes on which your job is running. (Actually I never thought that it was possible to monitor the state of a process via argv)

Comment: I would give it a shot with qrsh instead of qsub since the former is interactive. Even then I don't expect it to work as it's unlikely the job executor pings back its caller to update the arguments it was given.